# lenghts of paths from a DFS with incidence matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, depth-first-search

> So, i´d like to know the lenght of every path using a dfs algorithm, but my graph input is an **incidence matrix**. I know an implementation of a dfs algorithm in python, but it uses an adjacency list to represent a graph (a dictionary, in fact). Also, i only need to know the lenght of every path, not the path itself.

Does anyone know what kind of adaptation i need to make?

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far, along with a sample input and the expected output?